# Dojo Tree Menu Expand Node OnMouserOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

Hi i am using a dojo tree menu in my application. I am using onClick event to expand a particular tree node. I want instead that whenever i hover my mouse over the plus image it should expand the contents of that node just by hovering over of the mouse over it. Here is the code -

```
var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
        model: xyz,
        id: 'abc',
        showRoot: false,
        openOnClick: true,
```

How can i do it ? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dojo/on` event delegation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on#event-delegation):

```
// dependencies:
// var on = require("dojo/on");
// var mouse = require("dojo/mouse");
// var registry = require("dijit/registry");

on(tree.domNode, on.selector("img.dijitTreeExpandoClosed", mouse.enter), function(event) {
    var treeNode = registry.getEnclosingWidget(event.target);
    treeNode.tree._expandNode(treeNode);
});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/gUNuC/